# given that a policyholder has had a heart attack during the year, what is the probability that the policyholder is a jogger?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

40% of a company health isurance policy are joggers. rest are non joggers.for each non-jogger, the prob of having a heart attack is .4 the probability for a jogger to have a heart attack is .1 .

given that the policyholder has had a heart attack during the year, what is the probability that the policyholder is a jogger?

---

I started off doing (.4)(.1) + (.4)(.6)=.4 but that feels incorrect.

I know i should be using conditional probability but not sure how to go about this. Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: $(.4)(.1) + (.4)(.6)$ probably doesn't equal $.4$, because it's the same as $.4(.1 + .6) = (.4)(.7)$, which I doubt is equal to $.4$. (NB: I may have made a mistake. My algebra is rusty.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Suppose you has $100$ policy holders

- How many would you expect to be joggers?
- How many would you expect to be non-joggers?
- How many would you expect to be joggers having a heart attack?
- How many would you expect to be non-joggers having a heart attack?
- How many would you expect in total to be having a heart attack?

Now, what proportion of those having a heart attack would you expect to be joggers?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Baye's Theorem.
$$\frac{P(Guy is Jogger|Heart Attack victim)=[P(Guy is Jogger) * P(Heart Attack victim|Guy is jogger)]}{Total probablity}$$
Where Total probability :

$$P(Guy is Jogger)  P(Heart Attack victim|Guy is jogger) + P(Guy  ain't a jogger)P(Heart Attack victim|Guy ain't a jogger)$$

I can't think of a simpler answer. Cheers